# I don't understand why this query is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have a query that is slow against our microsoft sql database. And if I remove a part of it it's speeds up, but I don't understand why and the query planner is not helping me (there's something I'm missing).

Query that's slow >30 sec ([queryplan](https://ufile.io/nuq323mn)):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[CarImage] AS [t0]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Dismantled] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[DismantledId]
WHERE([t1].[FinishedReason] <> 0)
     AND ([t1].[FinishedDate] < GETDATE() - 365)
     AND (NOT(EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Part] AS [t2]
    WHERE([t2].[Status] <> 4)
         AND ([t2].[Status] <> 3)
         AND ([t2].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id])
)))
     AND (NOT(EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Part] AS [t3]
    WHERE([t3].[Status] = 3)
         AND ([t3].[SoldDate] > GETDATE() - 365)
         AND ([t3].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id])
)))
     AND ((NOT(EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Partner] AS [t4], 
         [dbo].[SelfPickSite] AS [t5]
    WHERE([t4].[Id] = [t1].[PartnerId])
         AND ([t5].[PartnerId] = [t4].[Id])
)))
          OR (EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[SelfPickCar] AS [t6]
    WHERE [t6].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id]
)));
```

If I remove the last part it's <1 sec ([queryplan](https://ufile.io/uk1yp3rt)):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[CarImage] AS [t0]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Dismantled] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[DismantledId]
WHERE([t1].[FinishedReason] <> 0)
     AND ([t1].[FinishedDate] < GETDATE() - 365)
     AND (NOT(EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Part] AS [t2]
    WHERE([t2].[Status] <> 4)
         AND ([t2].[Status] <> 3)
         AND ([t2].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id])
)))
     AND (NOT(EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Part] AS [t3]
    WHERE([t3].[Status] = 3)
         AND ([t3].[SoldDate] > GETDATE() - 365)
         AND ([t3].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id])
)))
     AND ((NOT(EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[Partner] AS [t4], 
         [dbo].[SelfPickSite] AS [t5]
    WHERE([t4].[Id] = [t1].[PartnerId])
         AND ([t5].[PartnerId] = [t4].[Id])
))));
```

Comment: Could you give some detail about the query and the part you removed? Without any context it will be impossible to help you

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally posted before adding all content. It's now updated.

Answer (score 0):

OR is performance killer ;
please try this query and give me the result

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].[CarImage] AS [t0]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dismantled] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[DismantledId]
        WHERE ([t1].[FinishedReason] <> 0)
            AND ([t1].[FinishedDate] < GETDATE() - 365)
            AND (
                NOT (
                    EXISTS (
                        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                        FROM [dbo].[Part] AS [t2]
                        WHERE ([t2].[Status] <> 4)
                            AND ([t2].[Status] <> 3)
                            AND ([t2].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id])
                        )
                    )
                )
            AND (
                NOT (
                    EXISTS (
                        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                        FROM [dbo].[Part] AS [t3]
                        WHERE ([t3].[Status] = 3)
                            AND ([t3].[SoldDate] > GETDATE() - 365)
                            AND ([t3].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id])
                        )
                    )
                )
            AND (
                (
                    NOT (
                        EXISTS (
                            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                            FROM [dbo].[Partner] AS [t4]
                                ,[dbo].[SelfPickSite] AS [t5]
                            WHERE ([t4].[Id] = [t1].[PartnerId])
                                AND ([t5].[PartnerId] = [t4].[Id])
                            )
                        )
                    )

                UNION ALL

                SELECT 1
                FROM [dbo].[CarImage] AS [t0]
                LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dismantled] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[DismantledId]
                WHERE (
                        EXISTS (
                            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                            FROM [dbo].[SelfPickCar] AS [t6]
                            WHERE [t6].[DismantledId] = [t1].[Id]
                            )
                        )
                )
        ) X
```

ps : if you have performance issue run this code `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and then run query and post the result

Comment: There seems to be an error here. You've typed Union all, union with what? above not exists?

Comment: Sorry I’ve posted via mobile, instead of or use 2 select statement